# Est-ce qu'on dit "patient pathologique" ou bien "patient" suffit pour écrire qu'il est atteint de tumeurs ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes, santé-et-médecine

Je voulais savoir la bonne utilisation du terme "pathologique". Est-ce que je me contente d'écrire "patient" pour faire référence au fait qu'il est atteint, dans mon cas, de tumeurs cérébrales, ou bien je dois mentionner "un patient pathologique" ou "patient atteint de tumeur cérébrale"?

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Gimanez , why you deleted _Merci_ ??

Comment: À ce compte là, est-ce qu'un patient qui ne serait pas pathologique serait *de facto* un malade imaginaire ? Je ne suis pas médecin, mais il me semble que "patient" suffit, et indique qu'il est sûrement atteint de quelque chose. Pour dire qu'il est atteint de tumeurs, j'utiliserais "patient atteint de tumeurs".

Comment: About the *Merci* deletion, have a look to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I love SE more and more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Patient* :

> [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=PATIENT)
>  DEF. — Personne, présentant des signes cliniques ou
>   non, qui consulte un médecin.
>
> OBS. — Le mot «patient» s'applique de nos jours à toute personne
>   justiciable de services médicaux ou paramédicaux ou qui y a recours,
>   qu'elle soit malade ou non. Il n'est plus strictement réservé comme
>   autrefois aux opérés (ou futurs opérés) ou aux malades qui souffrent.
>   Peuvent donc être appelés «patients» non seulement les malades [...],
>   mais aussi les individus qui se soumettent simplement à un bilan de
>   santé, à des analyses systématiques ou à des contrôles périodiques
>   [...]
>
> [*GDT*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299070)
>  Personne qui a recours aux services médicaux ou
>   paramédicaux, qu'elle soit [malade](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198746) ou non.

De plus, un patient [*pathologique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pathologique) pourrait être interprété familièrement comme un patient avec un comportement jugé anormal (*cas pathologique*, voir autres contextes pour l'utilisation de l'adjectif; aussi cas particuliers, [1](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&srchtxt=MALADE%20ATTEINT%20CANCER%20EXCEPTIONNEL), [2](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&srchtxt=MALADE%20ATTEINT%20CANCER%20TERMINAL)). « *Patient [atteint](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atteint) d'une [tumeur cérébrale](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=TUMEUR%20CEREBRALE)* » me semble usuel. Enfin, il s'agit d'[*information nominative*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8355502) et le patient a droit au [*secret professionnel*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=506576); cette information, incluant le fait qu'une personne soit un patient, ne peut faire l'objet d'aucune communication sauf dans les cas prévus par la loi.

Comment: interesting, and that answers my question :)

Comment: Oui, on est un "patient" à partir du moment où on est chez le médecin (ou à l’hôpital). Un "patient pathologique" peux être interprété comme une connotation péjorative, insinuant qu'il va [trop] souvent chez le médecin, qu'il va chez le médecin pour le plaisir de se plaindre, et qu'il est donc hypocondriaque, ou "malade imaginaire", ce qui implique une maladie mentale...

Comment: c'est aussi une façon de voir les choses @Random

Comment: @Amphiteóth Attention, il faut bien comprendre la nuance que je met dans mon explication, j'ai bien dit "peut être interprété comme une connotation péjorative". Le fait de dire "patient" décrit déjà parfaitement la situation. Le fait de dire "patient pathologique" peut donc être perçu comme une insistance volontaire, signifiant que la personne est malade au delà de ce pour quoi elle est "patiente". Je ne dis absolument pas que les gens qui vont souvent chez le médecin ont une maladie mentale.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Mon commentaire n'est qu'une reformulation (peut-être plus familière ?) de ce qui est dit dans la réponse, permettant (je pense) aux lecteurs de confirmer s'ils ont bien compris la nuance. La nuance étant plutôt subtile à mon goût, je pense qu'il est préférable de l'expliquer de plusieurs façons, comme moi (français maternel) je comprendrais cette expression si je l'entendais.

Answer (score 1):

Un `patient` désigne la personne qui consulte un médecin. Le mot `pathologique` ne s'applique pas à la personne malade, mais à la situation de cette personne. On dit par exemple que le patient `présente un cas pathologique`. Ne pas confondre avec `pathogène` qui traite de la cause de la maladie.